# To justify a complex-valued function is continuous

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

A complex-valued function is defined on the unit disk as $f(z) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1-tz} dt$. How can we show that the function is continuous ?

My Approach: As the integrand is analytic in $z$, it is well-defined. Hence $f$ continuous. The integrand is not analytic at $z=1/t$, which lies outside the unit disk.

Is this enough ? Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you delete https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4795541/42969 and post the identical question again?

Comment: @MartinR, as there was no answer, I thought of rewording the question.

Comment: Why not expand the fraction in geometric series and integrate term by term (or just argue that the result is a Taylor series absolutely convergent on all the discs of radius $r<1$)

Comment: Is the disk open or closed?

Comment: @Conrad, thank you ! Isn't there a simpler argument ?

Comment: Why don't you calculate $f(z)-f(z_0)$ and pull out $z-z_0$ ? The function is continuous for $z\notin [1,\infty).$

Answer (score 1):

The function $g:[0,1]\times\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{C}$ defined as $g(t,z)=\frac{1}{1-tz}$ is jointly continuous and for each $t\in[0,1]$, $z\mapsto g(t,z)$ is an analytic map on the unit disk. Choose a small disk $D$ contained in $\mathbb{D}$ with $\overline{D}\subset\mathbb{D}$. Then $g$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]\times\overline{D}$ so
$$f(z)=\int_0^1g(t,z)\mathrm{d}t$$ is continuous in $\overline{D}$.

Apply Morera's theorem to $f$ inside $D$ so that $f$ is actually holomorphic (analytic). Note that due to continuity of $f$ and Fubini's theorem, you can swap the order of integration.

Note that there was nothing special about $\frac{1}{1-tz}$, just that $g$ was continuous and for each $t\in[0,1]$, $z\mapsto g(t,z)$ was analytic.